# Regex to validate size units like 10,10Gi,10.5Mi,10Ki?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, validation, regex-group

I am using this regex `/\d+\.*\d*[KMG]i/gm` to validate size with units like 10Ki,10Mi and 10Gi but I am having a problem I want this only numeric value as well like 10,12,15 anything but my current regex allows only given below:

Regex : `/\d+\.*\d*[KMG]i/gm`

Allowed : 14.4Mi, 9.9Gi, 10Ki

requirement : 14, 14.4, 14.4Mi, 9.9Gi, 10Ki

Any help will be really appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the decimal part optional and the alphabetical characters at the end optional. You can do this using the question mark in regex:

```
\d+(.\d)?([KMG]i)?
```

Matches all your requirements

Answer (score 1):

```
\d+(.\d)?([KMG]i)?
```

This regex would match all your requirements.

FYI, You can play around with regex on https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

You could match 1 or more digit after the dot, and use word boundaries to prevent a partial match as well:

```
\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[KMG]i)?\b
```

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `\d+` match 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` Optionally match a `.` and 1+ digits using a non capture group
- `(?:[KMG]i)?` Optionally match one of `K` `M` G`followed by`i`
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F0gfp6/1)

Comment: thanks for sharing this it was really usefull.